# Undocumented setting in google calendar api "hideInvitationsSetting"

Tags: google-calendar-api

I found [settings list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/settings) now started to return `hideInvitationsSetting` setting. Not only this setting is not mentioned in docs, but also google search returns 0 results. Unlike `hideInvitations` it is not boolean but enumeration.

I am curious what this settings is for, is it deprecated on the contrary some beta setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HideInvitationSettings values depends on how you manage your invitations on your Google Calendar. To find that settings follow the steps below:

1. Go to Google Calendar.
2. At the top right, click Settings menu (gear icon) and then Settings.
3. On the left, under “General,” click Event settings and then Add invitations to my calendar.

[image]

Here's the values you can get depends on what you set in

**Add invitations to my calendar** setting**.**

1. **From everyone:** the value it will show in hideInvitationSetting is **NONE** as all invitation sent will be added automatically on your calendar.

[image]

2. **Only if the sender is known:** the value it will show in hideInvitationSetting is **UNKNOWN_SENDER** as it will not automatically add invitation to your Calendar from senders that is not on your contact list.

[image]

3. **When I respond to the invitation in email:** the value it will show in hideInvitationSetting is **UNRESPONDED** as invitation emails that you don't accept won't show up on your Calendar.

[image]

You can also replicate it by using this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/settings/get?apix_params=%7B%22setting%22%3A%22hideInvitationsSetting%22%7D).

**Reference:**

- [Invitation settings](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/13159188)